# Synchronously read csv file row by row nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, csv, express

I want to parse a csv file of 1000 rows one by one and perform action on each row. I am using `fast-csv` `npm` module. My code is reading csv file asynchronously and performing action, after complete file is read which is not according to my requirement.

```
exports.readCSV = function readCSV(fname, next) {
    var csv = require("fast-csv");     
    csv    
        .fromPath(path.join(__dirname, '/csv/'+fname) )
        .on('error', function(error) {
            next(null, {
                success: false,
                result: '',
                msg: 'Error reading server file'
            });
        })
        .on("data", function(data){
            console.log("read row");
            exports.dosomething(data);
        })
        .on("end",function(){
        })
}

exports.dosomething = function dosomething(data) {
    console.log("in dosomething");
};
```

Output I get is

```
read row
read row
in dosomething
in dosomething
```

However, expected output is

```
read row
in dosomething
read row
in dosomething
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove `dosomething` from exports and when data arrives use `dosomethig(data);`

Comment: Replace `exports.dosomething(data` with `console.log(data)`, test it and it works well...

Comment: Might want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371241/synchronous-processing-of-a-csv-file-using-fast-csv. The general idea (not mine) is to make the parser wait for dosomething() to be performed, and then read the next line. I assume that dosomething is a database write? Those are often cause for asynchronous execution flow.