# Synchronous processing of a csv file using fast-csv

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to process a csv file using fast-csv and here is my code.

```
    var stream = fs.createReadStream("sample.csv");
    csv.fromStream(stream, {headers : true})
    .on("data", function(data) {
            console.log('here');
            module.exports.saveData(data, callback)
        })
    .on("end", function(){
        console.log('end of saving file');
    });

    module.exports.saveData = function(data) {
    console.log('inside saving')
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is the process is not synchronous. 
The output that I am seeing is something like

here
here
inside saving
inside saving

But, What I want is

here
inside saving
here
inside saving

I am assuming we need to use async.series or async.eachSeries but not exactly sure how to use that here. Any inputs are greatly appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So you want to wait for `saveDate` to complete before continuing to parse the next row of CSV data?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pause the parser, wait for `saveData` to complete, and subsequently resume the parser:

```
var parser = csv.fromStream(stream, {headers : true}).on("data", function(data) {
  console.log('here');
  parser.pause();
  module.exports.saveData(data, function(err) {
    // TODO: handle error
    parser.resume();
  });
}).on("end", function(){
  console.log('end of saving file');
});

module.exports.saveData = function(data, callback) {
  console.log('inside saving')
  // Simulate an asynchronous operation:
  process.setImmediate(callback);
}
```

Comment: Wow this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @robertklep : can we call any promise inside on-data ?

Comment: @AmitPanwar should be possible, as long as you call `parser.resume()` _after_ the promise has been resolved/rejected.

Comment: I am calling parser.resume() in then clause but its not going inside promise, i have added console there which is being skipped

Comment: @AmitPanwar perhaps you should create a new separate issue for your problem.

Comment: sure, will do that

Comment: @robertklep, this worked for me but its being stuck at last row. After last row its not going to end.

Comment: @AmitPanwar might be a missing EOL character after the last line? I don't know if the CSV parser requires one to be present or not.

Comment: is it possible to execute ```saveData``` function asynchronously and perform some action only when all the ```save_data``` execution is done? because  ```end``` event does not wait for all the ```save_data``` executions to finish.

Comment: @vikaskv `saveData` is executed asynchronously already. However, it's possible (and even likely) that the `end` event is generated when the last `data` event has been generated, or when the last `data` event handler returns. That would not take into account any asynchronous calls inside of the event handler. You need to create a workaround for that.